# Can I catch arrows if I am not a monk?

Tags: dnd-5e, ranged-attack

Is there a way for someone who is not a monk to catch a projectile, similar to the monk's Deflect Missiles feature?

Let's say there are some bad people with bows. Can I ready my character to catch an arrow coming their way?

Answer (score 30):

## Yes, with Gloves of Missile Snaring

Just find a pair of [Gloves of Missile Snaring](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/gloves-of-missile-snaring) and you are set:

> These gloves seem to almost meld into your hands when you don them. When a ranged weapon attack hits you while you're wearing them, you can use your reaction to reduce the damage by 1d10 + your Dexterity modifier, provided that you have a free hand. If you reduce the damage to 0, you can catch the missile if it is small enough for you to hold in that hand.

Comment: Or just find a DM who would jury-rig a method. "Roll me a dex save higher than the attack roll."

Comment: @Jason_c_o You'd have to balance something like that out somehow otherwise you are getting a chance to avoid damage which only costs your reaction. I'd make the arrow do critical hit damage if you fail to stop it or something.

Comment: Costing you your action and your reaction, since the question asks about readying.

Comment: @Miniman I wasn't sure if Unstable Toad meant ready an action or make their character "ready" as in able to do it. Doing both would be kind of crazy since there is almost always something better you can be doing.

Comment: @Miniman I'd argue that the OP was just proposing readying an action as a possible solution to their own problem; this answer addresses what I perceive as their "true" question, which is about whether it's possible for non-monks at all.

Comment: @AllanMills: Expending your Reaction is a cost; or at least an opportunity cost. You only get 1 per round.

Comment: @Jason_c_o The thing to watch out for, as a DM doing that, is to make sure that you're not treading on the monk's toes. You don't want a system where you can pick one class and then do the things that the other classes can do just by sweet-talking the DM and making a skill check; it reduces the impact and value of class choices.

Comment: @anaximander I actually don't agree with that. The monk has an easier time of it, and that's the point. I don't agree with limiting what a player can do. We also allow characters to trip, disarm, etc, even if they aren't a battlemaster. (They just don't get a superiority die.) Classes are *better* at certain things, but that doesn't mean they should be the only ones doing it.

Comment: @Jason_c_o I agree with you on not limiting what characters can do unnecessarily. I'm just saying that whatever system you come up with for letting characters attempt to catch arrows, it should be less likely to succeed on average than the way a monk does it, or else you'll cheapen the monk's feature.

Answer (score 0):

**No, BUT:**

### **Do you need to catch it with your hands?**

Tell us a little bit more about your characters intent. Why do you need to catch an arrow in your hand - to string in your own bow and return fire?

If I were DM'ing, I'd ask what you wanted to accomplish - and if your character had a shield proficiency, I'd recommend discussing a series of actions that could result in you using a wooden shield as a reaction to stop the projectiles - and on your following turn, you could pull an arrow out for whatever purpose you had in mind.

While it certainly wouldn't be easy, it would be the best way I can imagine of doing what you want short of supernatural intervention.

Answer (score -1):

It's not necessarily a 5e solution, but in 4e Oriental Adventures (I believe) there was an option to design your own martial arts.  E.g. did you want a hard martial art like karate or a soft martial art like tai chi -- these styles defining the particular focus of the techniques -- are you offensively oriented or defensively oriented. Additionally you could pick various things that your variant could do (or use the preselected options).

It was based on 'buying' feats at various levels and building up your list of skills and maneuvers.  Basically at rank 1 you learned some basic kicks/punches/blocks and as you got more experienced you could add various more advanced techniques.  The techniques were all mundane and didn't require anything like Ki to operate.

While the rules were in that set of supplements, it wasn't so overpowering that it couldn't be merged in with a 'normal game', where not every character is surrounded by martial arts constantly.

Additionally, it was open to anybody (no class restrictions) -- though, Monks, would get the cool, super powered options.  Everybody else could learn some mundane version of skills...even though, some could get somewhat good.

This way everybody could have an option whereby they could learn a skill like catching arrows (and it being a codified method based upon real rules [the caveat being that it's 4e], not being totally a house rule.)